# textview is not fit inside fixed size height Relativelayout

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="270dp">

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#de7925"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Personal Mobile" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_backspace" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:text="QR CODE"/>    

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_capture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="SCAN CARD"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Content below header and above footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/barcode"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qrcode" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/barcode"
            android:text="Exchange"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorCallGradientStart"
            android:textSize="20sp" />            

    </RelativeLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my `XML`; the height of `RelativeLayout` is 270 dp. I have to fix all the things inside `RelativeLayout`.

How do i fit `TextView` inside i.e. fix for size of relative layout.

My current screen:

[image: current screen appearance]

this is my expected screen :

[image: Expected appearance]

The QrCode image view and textview are not fitting. I want to fit the text so you cannot see the text exchange.

Comment: for QrCode image view and textview  use linearLayout with weight

Comment: check out my answer it will fix your layout problem.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try This

Your image size is too large and you have also given the padding to textview that's why your text is not displaying.
I have changed your specific code.

```
<!-- Content below header and above footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/barcode"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/barcode"
            android:text="Exchange"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkGolden"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Remove padding in your `xml`

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Comment: i have to set text with padding

Comment: @MakleeLee use margin Instance of padding

Comment: Else Try like this:if you want to use padding  `android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="what ever you what"
    android:paddingRight="what ever you what"
    android:paddingTop="what ever you what"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Padding=10dp` in your textview but if you want to keep it. Change your `RelativeLayout` to LinearLayout and your layout will be good.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/barcode"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/qrcode" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barcode"
        android:text="Exchange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorCallGradientStart"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove text padding and also make text width `match_parent`, remove gravity and orientation in `RelativeLayout` have look

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/barcode"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/qrcode" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/barcode"
        android:text="Exchange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"    
        android:background="@color/colorCallGradientStart"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this-:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- Header aligned to top -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#de7925"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Personal Mobile" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_backspace" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:text="QR CODE"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_capture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="SCAN CARD"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Content below header and above footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/barcode"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qrcode" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/barcode"
            android:text="Exchange"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

instead of-:

```
android:layout_height="270dp"
```

to-:

```
android:layout_height="290dp"
```

Height is not as worth to fill all thimgs so change this and it will work